# AWS EKS managed node groups root volume encryption through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, encryption, amazon-eks, launch-template

I have been exploring AWS EKS managed node groups node root volume encryption through Terraform module. Found the below documentation from terraform, as this can be done by AWS-launch-template.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template

From the configuration details,

The ebs block supports the following:

*delete_on_termination - Whether the volume should be destroyed on instance termination. Defaults to false if not set. See Preserving Amazon EBS Volumes on Instance Termination for more information.
**encrypted - Enables EBS encryption on the volume (Default: false). Cannot be used with snapshot_id.***

But AMI id is from community AMI, so EBS volumes comes from Snapshot.

Now any approach about root volume encryption in AWS EKS Managed node groups node? I am using K8s version 1.21 now.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?